# SAS - How to find the max value between 2 or 3 numbers

Tags: sas, max, numeric

I have a table like this :

```
EMITTER   RECEIVER    DUR      T_DUR       PCT_DUR     PCUM     RANK_123 
123       12          6038      24843       0.243      0.243     1  
(...) 
123       578         256       24843       0.010      0.832    22.5
123       456         256       24843       0.010      0.842    22.5
(...)
```

I have a PROC SQL to every case where the rank is an integer. But when it's like 22,5 i have to choose a tiebreaker, so i want to pick the bigger one. 
(At this point, with just these variables, which tiebreaker would you choose?)

I tried this :

```
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE work.TESTE_UP_TOP22_123 AS
SELECT EMITTER, PCUM AS TOP22 
FROM WORK.BASE
WHERE RANK_123=22.5 AND MAX(RECEIVER); 
QUIT;
```

In the "teste_up_top22_123" i want to have the value of the emitter and value of the cumulative percentage (PCUM) where ranking is 22,5 and the value of the RECEIVER is bigger. 
So, it would stay:

```
EMITTER TOP22
123     0.832
```

How can i do this? 
And in the cases where i have more than 2 numbers with a ranking like 22,5, it's the same procedure?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the datatype of rank_123 a char? I don't understand how it can have a comma otherwise.

Comment: my mistake, it's 22.5

Comment: So it's not an integer?

Comment: numeric but not a integer, that's it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE work.TESTE_UP_TOP22_123 AS
SELECT EMITTER, PCUM AS TOP22 
FROM WORK.BASE
WHERE RANK_123=22.5
Having RECEIVER=MAX(RECEIVER); 
QUIT;
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm still new in SAS and didn't knew about "having" comand. helped  a lot!